# C# - SQL Server Data Tools - How to migrate from VS2010 to VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

We have a unit test project coded in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and using the "Microsoft.Data.Schema.UnitTesting" namespace (from SQL Server Data Tools 2010 I think).
For example we use classes like DatabaseTestClass.

We have been using Visual Studio 2013 for a while, but it's just now, when we uninstall Visual Studio 2010, that we notice that this namespace "Microsoft.Data", is not available anymore in VS2013.

I've been looking for alternate namespace and classes, but couldn't find any.
This project should be deprecated in a few months, so we don't want to spend time rewriting it.
But we need to be able to maintain it a little bit more.

Does somebody know a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest version of SSDT for VS2013 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx

In this version of SSDT, the database unit test code uses the namespace Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I already have installed the latest version of the data tools but when I try to add a reference to the project, the assembly is nowhere in the list (even if I change the target framework)

Comment: If you create a new, sample SQL Server Database Project and add a stored procedure, then you can right-click on the stored procedure and step through a wizard to create database unit tests for that stored procedure.  That wizard will create a new unit test project that you can use as a template for migrating your existing database unit tests.